# List inactive users within Azure active directory using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Looking to list all inactive users using PowerShell.

Ive tried many methods such as `Get-Aduser` etc.  but I always find recent users within the list.

Looking to query Azure AD so I can also get cloud accounts

I've arrived at below.

```
$users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | Where-Object { $_.AccountEnabled -eq $true }

$inactiveUsers = $users | Where-Object {

    $_.SignInActivity.DateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

} | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, UserType, CreationType

$inactiveUsers
```

However I find far too many results in the list and when I query some of these users I seen they have signed in within the last week showing that the script is not working as intended.

I'm wondering if what I'm looking to do is possible.   Find all users who have not signed in within the last 90 days?

Comment: You are comparing objects of different type in the condition `$_.SignInActivity.DateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)`.  Compute `(Get-Date).AddDays(-90)` _before the loop_ and convert it to string of the same template as `$_.SignInActivity.DateTime` (or to a number - the latter value could be e.g. epoch time or alike?)

Comment: At least this works `get-azureaduser -filter 'AccountEnabled eq true'` the true is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To list all inactive users using PowerShell within 90 days, make use of below script:

You can make use of **Microsoft Graph Module** to fetch the inactive users like below:

```bash
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "AuditLog.Read.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

$Inactiveusers= get-MgUser -Property DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, SignInActivity, UserType
$Inactiveusers | Where-Object {($_.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime -le $((Get-Date).AddDays(-30))) -and ($_.UserType -eq "Member")}
```

[image]

Note: Azure AD module will be deprecated on June 30, 2023.

**References:**

[azure-docs/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts.md) by besiler

[Azure AD PowerShell overview | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0)